# Doesn't work when i try to make it a function

Tags: python

So I've made this simple program in my programming course where it displays 100 random numbers between the interval -5 and 5 without consecutive repetition. I made first made it without a function but when i tried to define it, the code stoped working. For some reason is the "x" not in scope and I can't figure out what is wrong.

Any help is appreciated!

```
import random


def rand():
    lst = []
    y = 10

    for i in range(0, 100):
        x = random.randint(-5, 6)
        while x == y:
            x = random.randint(-5, 6)
        lst.append(x)
        x = y
    return rand


print(rand())
```

Comment: Did you mean to return `lst`? I don't get any errors relating to `x`; I just get the reference to `rand` printed out since that's what's being returned. This works fine if you replace `return rand` with `return lst`. Voting to close as a typo.

Comment: This isn't directly related to the problem, but what is the purpose of `x = y` at the bottom of the for loop?  `x` is reassigned at the top of the loop, so the effect of `x = y` is immediately lost.

Comment: Also, `y` is always 10, and `x` is a random number between -5 and 6, so `x == y` will never be true.

Comment: @JohnGordon I think they mean `y = x` instead. That explains both problems.

Comment: That's what i thought but I instead get another error: "NameError: name 'lst' is not defined"

Comment: @LudwigWallin if you `return lst`, you can't be getting that error. I just ran the code and it produced a list of random values. `return lst` in the function, not `(print(lst())` under the function.

Comment: I seem to have trouble with printing the function. It can't fint "lst"

Comment: @Carcigenicate Yeah mb. Its supposed to be y = x

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem here is: You are returning a function itself. It's possible in Python (you would be actually surprised how many things are possible there).

I am guessing that what you wanted to do is to return a list created in your `for` loop, so as @Carcigenicate pointed, it's probably a typo.

```
import random


def rand():
    lst = []
    y = 10

    for i in range(0, 100):
        x = random.randint(-5, 6)
        while x == y:
            x = random.randint(-5, 6)
        lst.append(x)
        x = y
    return lst


print(rand())
```

Comment: Yeah, thank you. y = x also solves the other problem :)